# How do I install a working demo?

Tags: commerce, installation-profiles

I have been struggling with this for quite some time. I am trying to install a demo of the Commerce module as provided by Centarro, but every time the install finishes, I only get an empty site with the Beograd theme enabled but no product catalogue at all.

Here's what I do every time I try.

1. I install the Commerce module via `composer create-project`.

   `composer create-project drupalcommerce/demo-project demo-commerce --stability dev --no-interaction`
2. I require the commerce_demo:2.0 package.

   `composer require drupal/commerce_demo`
3. Then I proceed with installing Drupal the standard way by going to my localhost URL. I select the profile provided by the commerce_demo module which should install the complete package.

However, every time the install finishes, there's still just an empty store with the Beograd theme enabled. I see that the products are created, as well as brand and category taxonomy terms but I don't get any working catalogue made using facets and search API.

Is there anyone who managed to get the entire demo working and can provide a file/database dump or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're hitting issues because the 2.x branch of Commerce Demo is intended to be used in the context of the new 3.x branch of Commerce Kickstart. This is a work in progress. If you're just trying to reproduce what we host at https://commerce.demo.centarro.io, I recommend the following tutorial:

https://www.centarro.io/blog/how-build-drupal-commerce-development-environment

Just bear in mind that even that is now outdated with the Drupal 8 EOL. You shouldn't have any issues for demo purposes, but I do think it should work fine with Drupal 9. I just haven't tested it yet.

Comment: You've just saved my weekend! Thank you a ton! Everything works as expected :)